# $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}, f(tx) = |t|f(x)$, prove $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(tx) = |t|f(x)$ for
>   $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is differentiable at
>   the origin, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

By the differencialibity criterion, $f$ is differentiable if there exists $r(v)$ such that

$$f(a+v) = f(a) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a) v_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}(a)v_m + r(v)$$

such that $\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{r(v)}{|v|} = 0$

Let's look at it in the point $a=0$, so:

$$f(0+v) = f(0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0) v_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}(0)v_m + r(v)$$

By the function relation in the question, $f(0) = f(0.x) = |0|f(x) = 0$, so:

$$f(0+v) = 0 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0) v_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}(0)v_m + r(v)$$

By the chain rule:

$$f(tx) = |t|f(x) \implies tf'(tx) = |t|f'(x) \implies f'(0) = f'(0\cdot x) \implies ?$$

I don't know how to get $f'(0)$ from above. Also, is the above derivation right? I'm confused because $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

So how can I prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple continuity argument shows $f(0) = 0$.

Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. The directional derivative of $f$ at $0$ in the direction of a unit vector $\nu$ is given by $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t\nu) - f(0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|t|}{t} f(\nu)$$ which exists if and only if $f(\nu) = 0$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$ the limit *must* exist, so we conclude $f(\nu) = 0$ for each unit vector $\nu$.

Finally if $x \not= 0$, then $\nu = x/|x|$ is a unit vector and $$f(x) = f(|x|x/|x|) = |x| f(x/|x|) = 0.$$

Comment: Why it works only for a unit vector?

Comment: I chose to use directional derivatives. A "direction" in that context is a unit vector.

Answer (score 0):

If $v\in\mathbb R$, the function $\ell_v:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$ defined by $\ell_v(t) = tv$ is differentiable. Becaause $f$ is differentiable, then $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $g(t) = f(tv) = |t|f(v)$ is also differentiable (it is just $f\circ \ell_v$). Remember: $f(v)$ is a constant and $t\mapsto |t|$ is not differentiable at zero on the real line. So the only way for $g$ to be differentiable is if $f(v) =0$.